# VBA: Find(date) is returning "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Tags: vba

I'm trying to find a date in a selected range as follows, however it keeps returning

> Object variable or With block variable not set

but I don't understand why. Could I please get some help with this?

'date_lasttrade' is a named range with the value '08/12/2017' inside, and that value is also within the range I am searching

```
Sub updatedata()

Dim date_today As Date
Dim date_lasttrade As Date
Dim date_difference As Integer

date_today = Worksheets("Summary").Range("date_today").Value
date_lasttrade = Worksheets("Summary").Range("date_lasttrade").Value
date_difference = Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Value - Worksheets("Summary").Range("date_today").Value

Worksheets("Match").Range(Range("A8"), Range("A8").End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Find(date_lasttrade).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: sorry should have added: the last line, where it searches for date_lasttrade

Comment: If it is the Find then it is not finding the value, check the value that is in variable and that that exact value if found in the range.  And remember to check to make sure that you are looking at true dates and not text that look like dates.

Comment: Pedantic note: `Find(date)` isn't *returning* an error message, it's *returning* `Nothing` because no match was found, and *your code is assuming that can't ever happen* and attempts to invoke `Nothing.Select`, which raises run-time error 91. Never assume `Range.Find` will find what it's looking for. This exact question was asked and answered hundreds of times over already.

Comment: And a warning - `Worksheets("Match").Range(Range("A8"), Range("A8").End(xlDown)).Select` will only work if "Match" is the active worksheet because it is equivalent to `Worksheets("Match").Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A8"), ActiveSheet.Range("A8").End(xlDown)).Select`.  You should always qualify your `Range` objects to specify which sheet they are acting on.

Comment: And, if you have formulas in column A of "Match", it's a good idea to specify `LookIn:=xlValues` as a parameter when doing your `Find` - just in case the user's last find was looking in formulas.